# Were lightsabers ever a "commodity"?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Lightsabers seem to be somewhat labor intensive to build.  And, from everything I've ever seen or read, a Jedi was responsible for creating their own.  Anakin Skywalker is shown to have lost several of them in the films, which I would assume result in a lot of lost time rebuilding new ones.  Was there ever a point where they were mass-produced?  That is, could you ever go to "Crazy Yoda's House of Lightsabers" and just purchase one?  Or was building one from scratch the only way of ever procur

Comment: There are at least oblique references in Zahn's books, and elsewhere in the EU, to non-Jedi wielding lightsabers.

Comment: +1 for "Crazy Yoda's House of Lightsabers"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not usually found in other places such as a store or such.  They are mainly used by Jedi's or Siths so it's not common for you to find it in a store.  According to the Star Wars Wikia about lightsabers during the Clone Wars there as at least one that was sold in a store.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber

> " At least one lightsaber was sold at a storefront for  credit 500,000
>   at Pons Ora during the Clone Wars.[28]"
>
> ↑ TCW mini logo Star Wars: The Clone Wars – "Missing in Action"

They were however mass-produced or at the very least common as it states here in the wikia

> "When the Clone Wars began, Jedi lightsabers experienced a change in
>   focus. Rather than being created as a meditative exercise, heavy-duty
>   lightsabers built to stand up to the rigors of war became the
>   norm.[26]"

So you can assume that they were mass produced for the Jedi's at around this point.  Previously they had only been for meditative purposes and not used for war.

After the Jedi Purge they were not that common though...

> Rhinann: "The weapons of the Jedi were destroyed along with the Jedi.
>   There are rumors that some lightsabers remain in the private
>   collections of the extremely wealthy. But the only one that I am
>   certain truly exists belongs to Darth Vader, and I doubt he'd part
>   with it willingly."
>
> Pavan: "A crystal then. I'll build my own. It'll be more in tune with
>   my—"
>
> Rhinann: "Adegan crystals, as well as Corusca, Ilum, and others, are
>   under strict trade and commerce interdiction, per the orders of
>   Emperor Palpatine."
>
> Pavan: "I'll grow one, then."
>
> Rhinann: "That may be possible. It will take some time, however, to
>   assemble the necessary equipment and materials."
>
> ―Haninum Tyk Rhinann elaborates on the illegality of lightsabers to
>   Jax Pavan

This implies that the necessary equipment and materials are rare at this point.

So overall before the Jedi Purge but after the Clone Wars there seemed to be a lot more than there was before the Clone Wars.

Comment: When you quote Wikia, you should ideally include what Wikia's references are for any statement

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that your second quote can legitmately be interpreted as "Mass-production".

Comment: The third quote also largely contradicts the fact that many sabers were powered by [synthetic crystals](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Synthetic_lightsaber_crystal).

Comment: Well not necessarily mass produced but at the very least common among jedi

Comment: @phantom42 not necessarily in the Wikia for the Synthetic Lightsaber crystal it states that the Jedi gathered natural formations of them.  "method of gathering of natural formations, which was looked on as relying on the "untamed wilds of space" to provide.

Comment: My point is more that he wouldn't really have to "wait" for one to grow if there is access to synthetic crystals. Wookieepedia states that it takes up to four days to synthesize. Compare that against how long it would have taken to track down/travel to natural ones.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are a very large amount of lightsabers, as shown in the second movie/episode Attack of the Clones, when Anakin Skywalker and Obi-wan were in the arena, the clones came to the rescue along with some jedis. They Anakin and Obi had lightsabers tossed to them. To me it seems like there might be a very large source of them, the most valuable resource needed is a Crystal.

Comment: This scene only depicts two "extra" lightsabers - the ones thrown to Anakin and Obi-Wan. Part of the Jedi's training is to build their own. So, there is going to be at *least* one lightsaber per Jedi. I'm not sure how that implies there is "a very large source of them".

Comment: I believe Spencer VDE is implying that since they were not owned by a Jedi, they must have came from a stockpile. Assumption to say there is "a very large source of them", however.

Comment: I am not saying that there was a very large source of them, except that the crystals are in fact grown which means that they would have a quite abundant source to make them.